# BigQuery [PHP] InsertAll Error: No records present in table data append request

Tags: php, google-bigquery

Everything seems to me working except for the last line of this function.  But it seems that the json (rows) is the problem...

Any help is appreciated!

Error:

```
Google_Service_Exception
Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/mtg/datasets/log/tables/v1/insertAll: (400) No records present in table data append request.
```

Table Schema:

```
raw_url         STRING      NULLABLE
endpoint        STRING      NULLABLE
parameter       STRING      NULLABLE
client_ip       STRING      NULLABLE
account         INTEGER     NULLABLE
response_code   INTEGER     NULLABLE
response_time   INTEGER     NULLABLE
datetime        TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE
```

Code:

```
public function insertLog()
{
    $rows = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllRequestRows;
    $rows->setJson('{"raw_url":"test","endpoint":"card.id","parameter":"1","client_ip":"127.0.0.1","account":1,"response_code":200,"response_time":1000,"created_at":"2014-02-14 19:16:21"}');
    $rows->setInsertId("21");

    $request = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllRequest;
    $request->setKind('bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest');
    $request->setRows($rows);

    $this->service->tabledata->insertAll($this->project_id, 'log', 'v1', $request);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllRequestRows should be named _Row not _Rows because you have to make an array of _Rows objects to pass the request.  Here is The code that finally worked.

Also, the json must be an object, not a json string. $data = the json_decode of the json string that was in the original question.

```
public function insertLog($data)
{
    $rows = array();
    $row = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllRequestRows;
    $row->setJson($data);
    $row->setInsertId( strtotime('now') );
    $rows[0] = $row;

    $request = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllRequest;
    $request->setKind('bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest');
    $request->setRows($rows);

    $this->service->tabledata->insertAll($this->project_id, 'log', 'v1', $request);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Saved a lot of time! I have an example repo at https://github.com/eRadical/google-api-php-client-examples would you be willingly to contribute this code? I can write it... or you can if you want/have time. Of course w/ correct attribution.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to share:
I make a little change because the code above didn't worked for me:
This line was a problem

```
 $this->service->tabledata->insertAll($this->project_id, 'log', 'v1', $request);
```

The problem is using the keyword $this->service. That's because the code didn't run inside a class. Instead of $this, you should use the $service

this is the full code of php google bigquery auth and php google bigquery insert that works for me:

```
    define("CLIENT_ID", 'my client id');
    define('KEY_FILE','key.p12');
    define('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME', 'its the email address as appear on the credential page');
    define('PROJECT_ID', 'my project');
    define('DATASET_ID', 'my data set');
    define('TABLE_ID', 'my table');

    $client_id = CLIENT_ID;
    $service_account_name = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME; //Email Address
    $key_file_location = KEY_FILE;

    // Cashing the client inside a session.
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");

    if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) 
    {
      $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
    }
    else
    {
        $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
        $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
            $service_account_name,
            array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'),
            $key
        );
        $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
        $client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);

        if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
        }
        $_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    }


   $service = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);


     $data = array( 'fields1' => '1', 'sample' => '2','maker' => '2');
    try {
    $rows = array();
        $row = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllRequestRows;
        $row->setJson($data);
        $row->setInsertId( strtotime('now') );
        $rows[0] = $row;

        $request = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllRequest;
        $request->setKind('bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest');
        $request->setRows($rows);

       $response =  $service->tabledata->insertAll(PROJECT_ID, DATASET_ID , TABLE_ID, $request);
print_r($response);

} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
} }
```

This response mean that there is no errors. go to check in the bigQuery and see the values:

```
Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllResponse Object
(
    [collection_key:protected] => insertErrors
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [insertErrorsType:protected] => Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllResponseInsertErrors
    [insertErrorsDataType:protected] => array
    [kind] => bigquery#tableDataInsertAllResponse
    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [processed:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Good luck all!

Comment: The problem is using the keyword $this->service.
That's because the code didn't run inside a class.  
Instead of $this, you should use the $service