# BigQuery [PHP] InsertAll : Not showing any error but BigQuery Table not affected with the inserted values

Tags: google-bigquery

I suffering the same problem on the link [BigQuery [PHP] InsertAll Error: No records present in table data append request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795683/bigquery-php-insertall-error-no-records-present-in-table-data-append-request). I followed the solution, error was removed but result is not affected on the BigQuery table my code is:

```
$data = '{"rows":[{"json":{"userId":"GR-003","state":"Pune","sales":"350"}}]}';
$data1 = json_decode($data);
try{
$rows = array();
$row = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllRequestRows;
$row->setJson($data1);
$row->setInsertId('9');
$rows[0] = $row;

$request = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllRequest;
$request->setKind('bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest');
$request->setRows($rows);

$service->tabledata->insertAll(PROJECT_ID, DATASET_ID , 'sample_table', $request);

} catch (Exception $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending the wrong object to big query. Change the `$data` to an object, and make sure you don't have `rows` and `json` level, also make sure variable `type` is correct as BigQuery is very strict, like `string`, `string`, `integer` or `float` if you have it.

```
$rows = array();
foreach() {
    $obj = new StdClass();
    $obj->userId='GR-003';
    $obj->state='Pune';
    $obj->sales=350;


    $row = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableDataInsertAllRequestRows;
    $row->setJson($obj);
    $row->setInsertId('9');
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: let me know if we want to insert multiple rows then how will be the object? can we take array of object and give that parameter to setJson ()?

Comment: No, you need to create new $rows for every object. See my updated answer. By the way where are you located?

Comment: I am from India, Mumbai